# How to know if user's current location is within or near polyline?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a location based tracking program where user can set his/her origin and destination point and then a polyline will be generated based on two coordinates. Now I want to know if user's current location is near or within polylines.

`List<LatLng> coordinates` is the coordinates that are used to draw polylines on Map.
`Stream<LatLng> currentLocation` is the stream that is listening to user's current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind 
I found out there is a method on native google map [PolyUtil](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-) **`isLocationOnPath()`** which return `true` if given point is within or near given List of coordinates.

I made a flutter plugin for that **[google_map_polyutil](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyutil)**

Comment: This library is `google_map_polyutil` is not maintained and can not be used on latest google maps

Answer (score 0):

First determine the value of "near" and you sould try to add or subtract this value to lat and long of the user and see if the new location has cross the line. (Signe of the addition or subtract has change).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I considered it using but I couldn't get exact result I wanted. I found a different method to solve this problem. 