# How to find current location is within bounds of list of coordinates getting from KML file in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. Will get list of coordinates from KML file
2. Need to find current location is within the bound of list of coordinates
3. Not using any google maps

gone through the reference [How to know if user's current location is within or near polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748693/how-to-know-if-users-current-location-is-within-or-near-polyline) but I am not using any native maps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.